# Why is my fs error returning an empty object in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, error-handling, fs

I am currently trying to read a file using `fs` in Node v12.16.2. I currently have a function setup like so:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
var JSONData;
const read = function(path){
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', (data, err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            console.log('there was an error');
        }
        JSONData = data;
    })
}
read('./path/to/file.json');
```

In the console, I simply get

```
{}
there was an error
```

I also tried `console.log`ing `err.message`, `err.valueOf`, and using `throw err`, none of which gave me any more data on the error. I'd appreciate if someone could help either discover my problem or knows it already.

Comment: is the path a valid path?

Comment: @Chana I believe so, though I can't really confirm since the error doesn't work :/. I'm using the directory relative to the file I'm starting with (as per usual with fs), though normally when it's invalid it tells me so...

Comment: You should be passing the error first and then the data. `(err, data)` https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks in Node.js receive the error as the first argument:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var JSONData;
function read (path) {
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', (err, data) => { // <-- Look here
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log('there was an error');
        }
        JSONData = data;
    })
}
read('./path/to/file.json');
```